# How to make yAxis data reach the top properly?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to set the number of tickInterval and  yAxis the max series data.
My method is set them after initialization of the Chart, like this:

```
this.barChart.yAxis[0].options.tickInterval = this.barChart.yAxis[0].dataMax;
this.barChart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0,this.barChart.yAxis[0].dataMax);
```

Seems like I can't the the max number before init chart. So I set it after Chart initialization. And It works like this:

[image]
After selecting part of them, the Reset Zoom button would show , Howver if it is cliked, tickInterval and extreme would change
[image]
Here is the pic :
[image]

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You can set the [tickAmount](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickAmount) or use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) and develop custom tick function.

Comment: If you set the max and tickInterval in the chart configuration options directly, it will solve this problem. The reset will honor those settings in that case. If your concern is setting them dynamically, there are numerous ways to do that while still having them be part of the configuration.

Comment: Additionally, you could use the **afterSetExtremes** event on the y axis, and within that function do a check - is the max properly set? If so, do nothing; if not, adjust to the appropriate value.  Reference:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.events.afterSetExtremes

Comment: @jlbriggs thx . But I wonder how to get max in the configuration? Is there a simple method to get max data of the categories

Comment: This is one of the many times when pre-processing your data and holding it in an array external to the chart is beneficial. If you can put up a fiddle of your chart and data, there are probably a few options of how to get what you need.